# How to convert var into hex value in bash?

Tags: bash, hex

How to convert text to hexadecimal in bash script?

Example:

```
#!/bin/bash
myvar="abc '\\ special chars, etc..."

# need $myvar in hexadecimal: 616263...
```

I tried:

```
myvar=`printf $plaintext | xxd --p`
```

But does not works, $plaintext contain special chars by example

```
$plaintext='demo && evil command injected'
```

How to convert var into hex value safely? or can save buffer to variable like this?:

```
printf $abc | xxd --p | def=
```

Comment: On another note: `printf $abc` is way too risky. use `printf "%s" "$abc"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used `xxd` before.  It seems that `xxd -p` will always group the plain output into columns, and you can't turn that off.  Instead, you can use `hexdump` for this.  It tends to be available on many Linux platforms.  Example:

```
myvar=$(hexdump -ve '1/1 "%02x"' <<< 'Hello, World!')
echo $myvar
```

Results in:

```
48656c6c6f2c20576f726c64210a
```

Comment: Thanks!, but remove final 0a.

Comment: Sorry, fix: myvar=${myvar%??}